# NSDateFormatter not recognizing dates

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I have an array that contains some date strings. I'm using NSDateFormatter but the problem is that it recognizes some of the dates and do not recognize others while all of them have the same format!

for example it formats: **Sat, 01 Feb 2014 08:44:00 +0430**

But returns null for: **Wed, 29 Jan 2014 17:40:00 +0430**

this is the code i used:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss xx"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateInput];
```

Comment: The hour format you used is for 0-12 format and not 0-24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this date format `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx"];`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateInput];
```

Note:

HH is denoted by 24 hour format

hh is is denoted by 12 hour format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx"];
```

Because, `HH` is syntax for 24 hour format which is suitable for your criteria.